# Javascript: Using window.open to initiate modal windows using multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, window.open

I wrote a function that allows an open window 'on-click' of a button.  It works fine.  However, I would like to be able to apply this code to several buttons without recreating the function over and over with a new name.  Here is what I originally have:

Function script:

```
function poponload()
{
    testwindow = window.open("http://www.google.com", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500");
    testwindow.moveTo(100, 100);
}
```

Button:

```
<input type="image" src="assets/buttons/pillButton_Process.png" onclick="javascript: poponload()" />
```

This is what I have now:

```
function poponload(url)
{
    testwindow = window.open("url", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500");
    testwindow.moveTo(100, 100);
}
```

Button:

```
<input type="image" src="assets/buttons/pillButton_Process.png" onclick="javascript: poponload(http://www.google.com)" /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
function poponload(url)
{
    testwindow = window.open(url, "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500");
    testwindow.moveTo(100, 100);
}
```

When you put quotes around "url", you're passing the string "url" and not the variable.

And call the function from your button like:

```
<input type="image" src="assets/buttons/pillButton_Process.png" onclick="poponload('http://www.google.com')" />
```

No need to keep the "javascript: " part in the onclick call, it's implied. And when you pass the url, enclose it quotes this time so you pass the string and not a variable.

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58N6n/1/)** so you can see it working.

Answer (score 0):

`second` `parameter` in the `window.open` is `window name`, pass the name as variable.
change the `method` as below

```
function poponload(url, name){
    testwindow = window.open(url, name, "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=500");
    testwindow.moveTo(100, 100);
}
```

**and HTML:** pass the name to method

```
<input type="image" src="assets/buttons/pillButton_Process.png 
                                        onclick="poponload('my_url','my_name');" />
```